# Adding a bridging header to an objective-c library breaks all framework symbols

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse library while writing an app in Swift. Trouble is, Parse is written in Objective-C and thus requires a bridging header for it to be accessible with Swift. The problem is, once I include the bridging header, Xcode loses all track of all library or framework symbols.

For example, without that header I can <kbd>cmd</kbd> click on a symbol and it takes to the place where it's defined. Or by doing an <kbd>alt</kbd> click on a symbol it shows me the comments for it's definition. Also, there's that beautiful thing - autocompletion that works.

With the header, I lose all code completion for things other than the Swift standard library and doing <kbd>cmd</kbd> click I get.

[image]

And as for <kbd>alt</kbd> click.

[image]

What could be the root of this?

P.S. the app compiles and runs on both the simulator and an iPhone. This has been tested on all Xcode 7 beta versions. This issue has been observed with other 3rd party frameworks, such as ones from Facebook and Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not the solution to your problem but you could use Parse pod from Cocoapods, so you wouldn't need the bridging header. Also you wouldn't need anything else.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Parse

Comment: I guess, what matters is the end goal and not the path to get there :)